# Autoreconf and <math.h> on Linux

Tags: c, autoconf

How I pass an '-lm' flag, or specify a library for inclusion, when using Autoreconf (Autoconf)?

The program includes  and I can compile like so:

```
gcc -std=c99 myprogram -lm
```

But when I compile vi Autoreconf, I get an error message saying

```
undefined reference to 'pow'
undefined reference to 'sqrt'
etc
```

The issue is on Linux, the same program compiles without error on OSX.

How do I edit configure.ac or Makefile.am to get the -lm flag to gcc?

Comment: As you wrote, it also compiles correct on Linux. `atuoconf` is a build-tool, not a compiler. So, the question is, if it also builds on OSX correctly - using the same tools.

Comment: It does, but build on Linux required some additional flags, -lm for one, -std=c99 for another.

Comment: You apparently **do** use different tools on both systems then. FYI: on Mac, `gcc` actually calls `clang`. These are different compilers, thus they might have different defaults and may require different options. In general it is bad practise to rely on the defaults of a tool. Apparently you use a pre-5 version of gcc on Linux, as that has `gnu90` default. Use a more recent version 5 and you get the default `gnu11` which should also compile C99 code. The default libraries are another such problem.

Comment: And you did not state you use the same build tools on both systems. As I pointed out already, this is a build issue, not a compiler problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `AC_SEARCH_LIBS([sqrt], [m])` to your `configure.ac`.

Comment: Also [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#index-AC_005fSEARCH_005fLIBS-344) for `ac_cv_search_sqrt` (cached) variable.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to your Makefile.am:

```
AM_LDFLAGS = -lm
```

This will link the math library to your program.